# How can I find the spatial reference system of a .las file?

Tags: esri, point-clouds

How can I read the .las header file to determine what spatial reference system (i.e projection system, datum, etc) that a LiDAR point cloud is using?

Answer (score 4):

The best answer can be found in [the ASPRS specifications](http://www.asprs.org/a/society/committees/standards/asprs_las_format_v12.pdf) for what should be included in an LAS header. Look for the LASF_Projection portion of the file.

> The projection information for the point data is required for all
> data. The projection information will be placed in the Variable Length
> Records. Placing the projection information within the Variable Length
> Records allows for any projection to be defined including custom
> projections. [The GeoTIFF specification](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/geotiff.html)  is the model for
> representing the projection information, and the format is explicitly
> defined by this specification.
>
> GeoKeyDirectoryTag Record: (mandatory)
> **User ID: LASF_Projection**
> Record ID: 34735
>
> This record contains the key values that define the coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for Erica is correct but partially (is based on the 1.2 las version), as in the new version of the .las format (1.4) there are quite important changes on the OORDINATE REFERENCE SYSTEM (CRS) REPRESENTATION:

Take a look at this:

http://www.asprs.org/a/society/committees/standards/LAS_1_4_r13.pdf